How to resolve error java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 502 cannotconnect"
This error we are getting while monitoring some applications if they are working as success or fails, sometimes the same code running fine but sometime with same code we are getting error:
java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 502 cannotconnect"
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(HttpURLConnection.java:2177)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:746)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:722)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:306)
    at com.ce.monitoring.service.impl.HomeService.crawl(PRMHomeService.java:80)
    at com.ce.monitoring.threads.HomeThread.call(HomeThread.java:71)
    at com.ce.monitoring.threads.HomeThread.call(HomeThread.java:21)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 502 cannotconnect"
10-Dec-2024 13:28:58.527 SEVERE [pool-200-thread-1] com.ce.monitoring.service.impl.HomeService.crawl home #Exception --java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 502 cannotconnect"
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(HttpURLConnection.java:2177)

how can we solve this error?

This usually means that the proxy got an error from the upstream server, so there's probably more information in the logs of that upstream server.
